# is it possible to generate RSA privatekey using modulus and exponent like did on Java side?

Tags: java, ios, swift, rsa, private-key

I am using RSA decryption on an iOS solution. I want to use the same parameters used on Java side to create the privateKey, but i am not able to find how.
is there a way to do it or is it possible to export this privateKey using Java and then import it on the iOS solutions ?

```
byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.decode("base64EncodedString");
byte[] DBytes = Base64.decode("anotherBase64EncodedString");
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes );
BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, DBytes);

RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPrivKey = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privKey = fact.generatePrivate(rsaPrivKey);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

My iOS application will decrypt a QRCode using this algorithme. the QRCode is encrypted using Java by a public key like below. to decrypt this code, we use the code above on Java side. so how we can generate the same privatekey that will be able to decrypt ? is it possible to do it without the same modulus and exponent ?

```
byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.decode("base64EncodedString");

byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.decode("AQAB");
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes );
BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);

RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKey = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPubKey);
```

Comment: Then you don't really have a private key, do you? In effect, your private key would really be the parameters used to derive your actual private key

Comment: no I don"t have the private key, I want to create it using modulus and exponent

Comment: There 2 scenarios. If the function that converts a modulus and exponent is deterministic (i.e. it produces the same answer for the same parameters, every time), then effectively, your modulus and your exponent become your private keys (because it would be trivial to use them to use them like you did, to create the actual RSA private key). And they're right there in your source code, for everyone to use. That wouldn't be secure.

Comment: It's like leaving a photograph of your house key, some key blanks, and some tools right on your front door beside the lock. Your key is not the only key, the combination of [photo, blanks, tools] is now a new key, that anyone else can come use to open your lock

Comment: On the other hand, if the key-derivation function isn't deterministic (i.e. it produces different results every time its called, even for the same params), then you're going to get randomized key pairs that aren't the same as what your server/java code got. So that won't be useful.

Comment: I don't know your use case, but what you're probably looking for is a key exchange mechanism like [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie–Hellman_key_exchange), in order to establish a shard encryption key between two parties connected over an insecure medium.

Comment: using this modulus and exponent, it produces the same answer private key

Comment: Then as I said, that means this encryption scheme is completely unsecure, borderline useless. Your modules and exponent become effectively become the private key, and they're right there for anyone to read from your app's code.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way it is supposed to work. You could generate a pair of private and public keys on each side, and exchange the **public** keys. The each side would encrypt the messages they wish to send (provided they are not too long) with the other side's public key, and decrypt the received messages with their own private key. But the private key is and should remain just that, **private**.

Comment: the public and private key created with above code, is already used on Server and Android version, so I need to create a similar one, else how can I figure it out ?

Comment: Although you may use the same code, the keys will not be the same, they are from your point of view effectively random. Each time you run the code you will get a new set of keys.

Comment: is it possible to export the generated private key using file format, like PEM or DER, and then use it on the iOS side ?

Comment: You could but you shouldn’t.